# Are there downsides to these JavaScript class definitions?

Tags: javascript

I have been defining methods like this:

```
Class Man {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.draw = (context) => { drawMan(context, this.name) };
  }
}
```

I have become aware there is another method of defining methods, which looks like this:

```
Class Man {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  draw(context) { drawMan(context, this.name) };
}
```

Are there significant downsides to my approach?

Comment: post your code here on the site and not an image of it

Comment: Defining methods on the instance instead of the prototype may actually (*barely*) increase performace, but could have significant ramifications in terms of memory use.

Comment: hey man thanks for the answer looks like i dont need to panic about this

Comment: @Gershy, do you care to explain a little bit and post it as an answer..

Comment: First one adds a different `draw` property to each instance created using `new Man` while the second one adds a `draw` property to `Man.prototype` and nothing gets added to each instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this.draw = (context) => {drawMan(context,this.name)};

This line will create property in the instance of class with arrow function inside. This means:

1. This function will be created per instance (1000 instances = 1000 functions). Which means more time for instantiation, more memory usage, more pauses from the garbage collector later on. The good part is that using this approach you will not bothered with context and can safely pass this function to the consumers as argument.

> draw(context) { drawMan(context, this.name) };

2. This line creates function in the prototype of the class. Which means that it will be created only once, no matter how much instances you will create later. But in this case you should know, that this function may change the context (`this`) when called. So it's not safe to pass it as argument in case it uses `this` somehow;

So, from my point of view. If you are not using anything from `this`, or function is internal (you don't plan to pass it as argument somewhere), use the second option. If it is not internal and uses `this` - use the first one.

P.S. there is the mixed approach if you want to keep function in prototype, but also save context. You might want to use `bind` function like here:

```js
class MyClass {
    name = 'test';
    test() { console.log(this.name); }
    constructor() {
        this.test = this.test.bind(this);
    }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
const test = instance.test;
test();
```

In this case you will have the main function in the prototype and it will be created only once. And when you will create new instance you will create only wrapper for this function with the binded context.

Comment: Just to be clear - in 95% of the cases you shouldn't worry about this too much. Use what fits you best.